# DirectX11 Template for windows 10?

Tags: windows, directx, directx-11

In the [tutorial online for DirectX development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/tutorial--setting-up-the-games-infrastructure), there is an option for DirectX11 App on Windows 10, but on my Windows 10 machine I only get the option for DirectX11 App on 8.1. Why is that? What do I have to install to develop DirectX 11 on Windows 10? Does it matter?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain because I'm still using Windows 7. But 8.1 for DirectX 11 was designed for Windows 8.1 and I do know that Windows 10 the entire operating system was redesigned and built around DirectX 12 which in a way does away with the old style HAL system giving graphic developers more control but it also increases their responsibilities as a developer. This is why some have said that DirectX 12 is "closer to the hardware" since it communicates from the API - OS directly to the hardware instead of having a middle man or that abstraction layer.

Comment: I would say that the API for DirectX 11 that is 8.1 would be the way to go if you are looking to develop DirectX 11 as opposed to DirectX 12 on Windows 10. You should be able to get this from the Windows SDK found here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: What the main difference is with the 8.1 build of DirectX 11 API or SDK is that it has more feature sets and commands that are available for development of Windows 8 over Windows 7 other than those extra or added feature sets or feature levels the API is basically the same. The only one that is completely different is DirectX 12.

Comment: The tutorial doesn't mention any specific Windows version. What do you mean?